# Using pp after a name as an adjective

Tags: adjectives

If I want to mention the condition in which something, for example the light, is exposed to something else like the wind and I am exposed to the first thing (the light), can I say:

> I am exposed to the light, exposed to the wind.

(The light is exposed to the wind and I am exposed to the light)

Is it correct? Should I use comma as I did in the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what *the light is exposed to the wind* means, so I'll consider a more meaningful utterance that I think illustrates the same syntactic/semantic principles...

> *She held the baby[**,**] **eating ice-cream***

...where the highlighted clause (the "condition") is "ambiguous", in that it could refer to what ***she*** was doing *while holding the baby*, or what ***the baby*** was doing *while being held.*

If we substitute ***the pram*** for ***the baby*** in my example, the only possible interpretation is that ***she*** was the one eating ice-cream. Equally, if we substitute ***the pram*** for ***she***, it must be ***the baby*** who's eating the ice-cream. But these are "pragmatic" interpretations - dictated by our knowledge of what's possible in the real world, not by the "grammar" as such.

Apart from pragmatism (which interpretation is *more likely?*) the most important "rule of thumb" is that we normally associate the potentially ambiguous final clause with *the nearest preceding noun phrase that makes sense*.

---

***But*** if that ambiguous clause is separated from the primary statement by a comma, this heavily tips the balance towards *moving further leftwards* to find the relevant referent (the comma represents a *pause* in speech, which places greater syntactic/semantic "distance" between the preceding and following elements). Thus in my example, if the comma *is* present we should assume ***she's*** eating ice-cream, not the baby.

Note that this needn't imply that if the comma *isn't* present we should *always* assume the referent is the immediately-preceding noun phrase (***the baby*** in my example). It's effectively a stylistic choice whether to include the comma even if we have ***the pram*** rather than ***the baby*** - but since prams can't eat ice-cream, only one possible interpretation can apply anyway.